# Error after registration usnig laravel ui

Tags: php, laravel, swiftmailer

after i click register button i get the error bellow
`Swift_TransportException Process could not be started [The system cannot find the path specified. ]`
and whene i go to phpmyadmin it seems that i have the new user record in my database
i don't know what's the relation between the **auth** and **swiftMailer**
i already tried clearing the config using `php artisan config:clear`  changing `MAIL_DRIVER, MAIL_HOST, MAIL_PORT` i don't know what to do

this is my `.env` file

```
APP_NAME=****
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:****
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=****

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_DATABASE=db
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=localhost
MAIL_PORT=2525  
MAIL_USERNAME=
MAIL_PASSWORD=
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=from@example.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME=Example
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

and this is the `config/mail.php`

```
<?php

return [

    'default' => env('MAIL_MAILER', 'smtp'),
    //'default' => env('MAIL_MAILER', 'sendmail'),


    'mailers' => [
        'smtp' => [
            'transport' => 'smtp',
            'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
            'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
            'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
            'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
            'timeout' => null,
            'auth_mode' => null,
        ],

        'ses' => [
            'transport' => 'ses',
        ],

        'mailgun' => [
            'transport' => 'mailgun',
        ],

        'postmark' => [
            'transport' => 'postmark',
        ],

        'sendmail' => [
            'transport' => 'sendmail',
            'path' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
        ],

        'log' => [
            'transport' => 'log',
            'channel' => env('MAIL_LOG_CHANNEL'),
        ],

        'array' => [
            'transport' => 'array',
        ],

        'failover' => [
            'transport' => 'failover',
            'mailers' => [
                'smtp',
                'log',
            ],
        ],
    ],

    'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
    ],


    'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',

        'paths' => [
            resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
        ],
    ],

];
```

Comment: You should try `MAIL_HOST` as `smtp.gmail.com`

Comment: already tried this solution always same error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found where the error exactly is in my user model. I have this:

```
class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
```

First, make sure to use the recomended `MAIL_DRIVER` and `MAIL_HOST` values.
Else, look for anything that has a relation with email in your model. In my case, I simply removed the inmplements.

````
class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
```
to
```
class User extends Authenticatable
```
````

Answer (score 0):

Change `MAIL_HOST` to `smtp.mailgun.org` in your `.env` file, considering that the `.env` file values are more priority.

Comment: already tried this solution  same error message :(